# Calling on a function within another function in python

Tags: python, function

I am attempting to call on a previous function that I created within another function but it does not seem to be working at all. I am new to python and I am trying to learn so any help will be happily received. Here is the code that I have been working on:

```
# Converts temperature celsius to farhenheit
def celsius_farhenheit(temp_celsius):
    temp = temp_celsius * 1.8 + 32
    return temp
#Tests the celsius to farhenheit conversion function
t1 = celsius_farhenheit(20)
print t1

#Converts farhenheit to celsius
def farhenheit_celsius(temp_farhenheit):
    temp = celsius_farhenheit(temp_celsius)
    celsius = (temp - 32) * 5/9
    return celsius
#tests the farhenheit to celsius conversion function
t2 = farhenheit_celsius(40)
print t2
```

The error I get is:

> NameError: name 'temp_celsius' is not defined

I understand that `temp_celsius` is not defined in my `farhenheit_celsius` function only in my `celsius_farhenheit` function. I guess I am trying to figure out how to call upon my `celsius_farhenheit` function and implement it into my `farhenheit_celsius` function to get the correct farhenheit to celsius conversion.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Your code logically does not make sense. Your Fahrenheit->Celsius conversion has a temperature in Fahrenheit.  What's the point of the temp variable in your calculation? It doesn't belong there.

Comment: If you already had temp_celsius, you could return it without doing the calculation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should fix your code. your code had syntax and logical error.

i have edited your code and commented unwanted lines

you have to comment the `temp=` line and change `celsius = (temp - 32) * 5/9` to `celsius = (temp_farhenheit - 32) / 1.8`

```
# Converts temperature celsius to farhenheit
def celsius_farhenheit(temp_celsius):
    temp = temp_celsius * 1.8 + 32
    return temp
#Tests the celsius to farhenheit conversion function
t1 = celsius_farhenheit(20)
print t1


#Converts farhenheit to celsius
def farhenheit_celsius(temp_farhenheit):
    #temp = celsius_farhenheit(temp_farhenheit)
    #print temp_farhenheit
    celsius = (temp_farhenheit - 32) / 1.8
    #print celsius
    return celsius
#tests the farhenheit to celsius conversion function
t2 = farhenheit_celsius(68)
print t2
```

the first function converts 20 C to 68 f

the second function converts 68 f to 20 C

you can easily debug by properly placing print statements like the print statements i've commented in second function.

Answer (score 0):

f_c gets the temperature in farhenheit and calculate`(temp_farhenheit- 32) * 5.0/9` 
c_f gets the temperature in Celsius and calculate `temp_celsius * 1.8 + 32`

So basically what you want is:

```
# Converts temperature celsius to farhenheit
def celsius_farhenheit(temp_celsius):
    temp = temp_celsius * 1.8 + 32
    return temp
#Tests the celsius to farhenheit conversion function
t1 = celsius_farhenheit(20)
assert t1 == 68 # since 20 Celsiusare 68 fahrenheit 

#Converts farhenheit to celsius
def farhenheit_celsius(temp_farhenheit):
    celsius = (temp_farhenheit- 32) / 1.8
    return celsius
#tests the farhenheit to celsius conversion function
t2 = farhenheit_celsius(40)
assert t2==(4+4.0/9) # since 40 fahrenheit are 4.444 Celsius
```

Note that I changed 
 `celsius = (temp_farhenheit- 32) * 5/9` 
to be: 
`celsius = (temp_farhenheit- 32) / 1.8` 
So now it returns a floating point.
In order to test yourself you can also do this:

```
x=40
assert farhenheit_celsius(celsius_farhenheit(x)) == x
```

Since this composition gives the [identity function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_function)